# Finding nCr for code-golf

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, python

The problem is to compute nCr = n!/(r!) * (n-r)! in the fewest characters possible. The input will be in the form: 1st line will have number of test cases and second line will have n and r for each testcase. You need to print ncr

e.g.

```
Input
1
100 10

Output:
17310309456440
```

Here's what I have in python. Is there a way to reduce the number of characters further ?[143 chars presently]

```
r=raw_input
f=lambda x:0**x or x*f(x-1)
C=lambda n,r:f(n)/f(r)/f(n-r)
for i in range(int(r())):print C(*map(int, r().split()))
```

Thanks!

Comment: `from sympy import binomial`

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 (100 chars)

```
I=input
C=lambda n,r:r and C(n-1,r-1)*n//r or 1
for _ in' '*int(I()):print(C(*map(int,I().split())))
```